# How to send private message to facebook user using java

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to send private message to my friends on facebook using java.
I have already searched enough on Google about this.
It seems earlier it was not possible but it is possible as i have seen this on many sites.

I also have read enough posts on stack overflow but could not find the answer.

please can someone point me in the right direction.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: nice one Holger..but it would be better if you had come up with something which might be useful to me as well as all other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what sort of application are you talking about here?
is it server side java?  desktop java application?
can you use some sort of facebook sdk?

you basically have two possibilities:

(1) the fb chat api (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/)
it's a xmpp (like) protocol, and once the user grant you the permission you can connect on his behalf to the fb xmpp server, and send messages as the user.

(2) the send dialog (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/)
for this you need to actually open a fb ui dialog for the user, with which he himself can send a message.  for this you need to have a ui.

Comment: Yes, it is server side java application & I am using spring framework..I have tested the second option but that requires code to be put in html code. You can assume I have some data which i want to send as message, I have access token of logged in user and user id of the friend whom i want to message..Now i just want to call some function which can take these values as parameter and post message in user's friend's inbox..

Comment: well then, your only available option is the first one i suggested.  you need to implement the xmpp protocol, and ask your users for the xmpp_login permission (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot Nitzan Tomer..Lemme try your suggestion also. If you come up with any other solution please share..

Comment: Can you check out buy.com Below there is an option shopping with friends..Developer has implemented the option of private messaging to users.If you find any useful info please share.

Comment: when you click that option, it opens a page with a "login to facebook" button.  if you click that button it will then ask you to approve their facebook application, in the permission list for that application you can clearly see the "Access Facebook Chat" permission which is exactly the 1st option i suggested for you.

Comment: Yeah Nitzan, observed the same..Thanks for your help :)